# jQuery Trigger Event in AngularJS Karma Test

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a new directive I'm writing.  However, I can't seem to get the keydown event to trigger with jQuery inside Karma/Jasmine.

Here is a simplified version of the test :

```
'use strict';

describe('', function() {

  var $compile;
  var $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  }));

  describe('Getting Trigger To Work', function() {

    it('Should Trigger a KeyDown Event', function() {

      var el = $compile('<form name="testing"><input id="field1" name="testfield" ng-model="result" type="text" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50"/></form>')($scope);
      console.log(el);

      var inputEl = el.find('input');
      console.log(inputEl);

      var e = $.Event('keydown');
      e.which = 65;

      inputEl.trigger(e);

    });

  });

});
```

My karma config includes AngularJS and jQuery.  Here's that section:

```
//
files: [
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
  'test/**/*Spec.js'
],
```

When I run the test, I get an error that my input element has no trigger method :

```
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/dev_libraries/val-on-timeout/test/valOnTimeoutSpec.js".
LOG: Object{0: <form name="testing" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"><input id="field1" name="testfield" ng-model="result" type="text" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></form>, length: 1}
LOG: Object{0: <input id="field1" name="testfield" ng-model="result" type="text" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">, length: 1}
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.5)  testing valOnTimeout Should load FAILED
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'trigger'
        at null.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Macintosh HD/dev_libraries/val-on-timeout/test/valOnTimeoutSpec.js:79:21)
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.5): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.327 secs / 0.033 secs)
```

At first, you may think that jQuery is not included.  However, it is included.  If it were not, the test would fail at `$.Event`.

Suggestions on getting the keydown event to work on the input?

Comment: That's the problem.  `[object Object] has no method 'trigger'` so, I can't trigger any event.

Comment: sorry, I meant `angular.element(inputEl).trigger('keydown')`

Comment: @dcodesmith Thanks.  Tried. No luck.  Still `Object [object Object] has no method 'trigger'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this works

```
  var e = $.Event('keydown');
  e.which = 65;

  $(inputEl).trigger(e); // convert inputEl into a jQuery object first
  // OR
  angular.element(inputEl).triggerHandler(e); // angular.element uses triggerHandler instead of trigger to trigger events
```

Comment: I got another identical answer via Twitter, but you get the vote here.  `$(inputEl).trigger(e)` did the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: load jQuery before AngularJS.

> At first, you may think that jQuery is not included. However, it is
>   included. If it were not, the test would fail at $.Event.

You have 2 dependencies on jQuery here:

1. `$.Event`, a direct reference; and
2. `$`, indirectly referenced by `angular.element()`;

When AngularJS is loaded, it looks for a previously loaded jQuery instance, and in case it does exist, it makes `element` just an alias to `$`. Otherwise it loads a reference to jqLite, which does not have a `trigger` method.

So, I'm sure you do have jQuery loaded, but that does not mean AngularJS will use it. To do so, you must ensure jQuery is loaded (anywhere) before AngularJS.

When `angular.element()` refers to jqLite, it would never call jQuery, even after jQuery is loaded. So you can only call methods defined on jqLite:

```
angular.element(inputEl).triggerHandler(e);
```

However, jqLite's `triggerHandler` would not perform event bubbling, it's not reliable to mock raising events. jQuery's `trigger` is way better.

To use jQuery, do this on your HTML:

```
<script src="jquery.js">
<script src="angular.js">
```

Or on your karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
  'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'test/**/*Spec.js'
],
```

Reference:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1608

> Suggestions on getting the keydown event to work on the input?

You have found one approach by working-around the problem. It's not a big deal for your *unit tests*, where you would want a better DOM library, but now you know what's going on.

PS: I really liked answering this one. A question from more than a year, viewed by 6k users, and still no answer to the *core* problem.