# Angularjs - simulate touch event in Protractor e2e test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I use Protractor with Jasmine for my mobile Angularjs app. I want to test a touch event (touchStart / touchEnd etc...) on a particular element. Something like:

```
it('should play video', function(){
    var poster = by.css('.video-poster');
    element(poster).??? //Simulate touch event here
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update:

Since Protractor returns a Selenium element finder not an angular element, you'll have to use the `executeScript()` function to call a JavaScript method on it, like:

```
var poster = element(by.css('.video-poster'));
browser.executeScript(
    'angular.element(arguments[0]).triggerHandler("touchstart");', poster);
```

### Original:

You should be able to trigger the event, like:

```
element(poster).triggerHandler("touchstart");
```

If you need more stuff in the event object, you can create one like this answer: [jQuery Trigger Event in AngularJS Karma Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211036/jquery-trigger-event-in-angularjs-karma-test/21211207#21211207)

**Note:**

It seems Angular does not provide you with `trigger()` method like jQuery, only `triggerHandler()`, as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: TNX for the answer. This did not work for me. I get:  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'trigger'. It might be related to the fact that this is a Protractor test and the element is not a regular jQuery element

Comment: Hey, sorry, I didn't follow up when the comment was incomplete. By now you hopefully have come past it, but if not, see if the updated version helps.

Comment: Hey. tnx again for the answer. triggerHandler resulted in similar error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'triggerHandler'. I guess the element(by.css('.video-poster')) is not a jqLite element as well...

Comment: Oops, forgive my ignorance. Yes, it's a Selinium element finder https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#protractorby

Comment: Thanks man! this is working (I had to add "browser" to "executeScript" in your last update).

Comment: thanks m8, but what if I want to simulate a touchStart, a move and then a TouchEnd event?

Comment: have you tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor/25667634#25667634