# Simulating/triggering touch events in Protractor scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm looking for a way to trigger touch/swipe events during my Protractor test scenarios.

I know that the underlying Selenium [JsonWireProtocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) supports it, but it seems like it has the requirement of using appium (which I'd rather not use).

I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720823/angularjs-simulate-touch-event-in-protractor-e2e-test) which triggers/tests very specific touch events, but I'm not trying to test the events themselves - I just want to navigate the app like a user would (and test what comes AFTER they've navigated through it).