# How to spec Sortable with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, jquery-ui-sortable

I wrote some code to test Sortable with protractor:

```
  it('test Sortable', function(done) {
    var originText, liElems, items, itemList,
        driver = browser.driver

    this.timeout(10000)
    driver.get('http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/')
    itemList = driver.findElement(By.id('foo'))
    items = function() { return driver.findElements(By.css('#foo > li')) }

    items().then(function(items) {
      liElems = items
      return Promise.map(liElems, function(liElem) { return liElem.getText() })
    }).then(function(texts) {
      originText = texts
      //return driver.actions().mouseMove(liElems[7]).mouseDown().mouseMove(liElems[1]).mouseUp().perform()
      return driver.actions().dragAndDrop(liElems[7], liElems[1]).perform()
    }).then(function() {
      return Promise.map(items(), function(liElem) { return liElem.getText() })
    }).then(function(newText) {
      expect(newText).to.not.eql(originText)
    }).then(done()
  })
```

I tried `mouseMove`, `dragAndDrop`, but it not work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor

Comment: @Aaron No, you can find I have already tried this way, but it not work for me.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: @EhsanAli Not yet 