# How to simulate a drag and drop action in protractor in angular2?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, protractor, e2e-testing

I have two divs.

```
var e1 = element(by.id('draggable-0'));
var e2 = element(by.id('dropContainer-0'));
```

I want to drop `e1` in `e2` .i.e. implementing drag & drop in e2e test case for angular2.

I tried below code:

```
var e1 = element(by.id('draggable-0'));
var e2 = element(by.id('dropContainer-0'));
browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(e1.getWebElement(),e2.getWebElement()).perform();
browser.sleep(2000);
```

but its not working.My chrome gets opened but nothing happens.

any inputs?

thanks.

Comment: How is the drag and drop implemented in the page? can you provide the html?

Comment: in page they are two different components. I have used `ng2-dnd` library for drag n drop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a drag and drop action in protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your page implements an HTML5 drag and drop which is not supported by the Selenium `dragAndDrop` action.

You can however simulate the action by injecting the `dragenter, dragover, drop, dragend` events with `executeScript`:

```js
const JS_HTML5_DND = 'function e(e,t,n,i){var r=a.createEvent("DragEvent");r.initMouseEvent(t,!0,!0,o,0,0,0,c,g,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),Object.defineProperty(r,"dataTransfer",{get:function(){return d}}),e.dispatchEvent(r),o.setTimeout(i,n)}var t=arguments[0],n=arguments[1],i=arguments[2]||0,r=arguments[3]||0;if(!t.draggable)throw new Error("Source element is not draggable.");var a=t.ownerDocument,o=a.defaultView,l=t.getBoundingClientRect(),u=n?n.getBoundingClientRect():l,c=l.left+(l.width>>1),g=l.top+(l.height>>1),s=u.left+(u.width>>1)+i,f=u.top+(u.height>>1)+r,d=Object.create(Object.prototype,{_items:{value:{}},effectAllowed:{value:"all",writable:!0},dropEffect:{value:"move",writable:!0},files:{get:function(){return this._items.Files}},types:{get:function(){return Object.keys(this._items)}},setData:{value:function(e,t){this._items[e]=t}},getData:{value:function(e){return this._items[e]}},clearData:{value:function(e){delete this._items[e]}},setDragImage:{value:function(e){}}});if(n=a.elementFromPoint(s,f),!n)throw new Error("The target element is not interactable and need to be scrolled into the view.");u=n.getBoundingClientRect(),e(t,"dragstart",101,function(){var i=n.getBoundingClientRect();c=i.left+s-u.left,g=i.top+f-u.top,e(n,"dragenter",1,function(){e(n,"dragover",101,function(){n=a.elementFromPoint(c,g),e(n,"drop",1,function(){e(t,"dragend",1,callback)})})})})';

var e1 = element(by.id('draggable-0'));
var e2 = element(by.id('dropContainer-0'));
browser.executeScript(JS_HTML5_DND, e1.getWebElement(), e2.getWebElement());
```

The source of the drag and drop script:

https://gist.github.com/florentbr/60ef7cb8d9b1ae690cafc82aad52da73#file-drag-drop-js

Comment: Tried this, it hangs the chrome. i.e. my app would not get open in chrome after adding this.

Comment: I just test it on http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd and it worked as expected.  It could be that your version of protractor doesn't resolve the provided elements. Try with `browser.executeScript(JS_HTML5_DND, e1.getWebElement(), e2.getWebElement());`. Also try `browser.driver.executeScript(JS_HTML5_DND, e1.getWebElement(), e2.getWebElement());` to see if it's a sync issue.

Comment: it says target element is not draggable.but I have applied draggable directive on the same element

Comment: The source element should have the `draggable` attribute set to `true`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable