# How do drag and drop a element from that elements position to another elements position just below it using Node Js and Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the below code but it seems it is not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).then(function (element1) {              
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).then(function (element2) {                                                  
      .then(() => driver.actions().dragAndDrop(element1,element2).perform())
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the innermost `.then` called from? did you put the code correctly?

Comment: I am new to nodejs, I thought it has done in that format

Comment: Also please give relevant HTML for better solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an overly complicated code. You can simply use the `dragAndDrop()` method to achieve this in this way -

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem, target).perform();
```

where `elem` is the source element and `target` is the target element.

Edit 1 : OP mentioned that the webpage is an Angular webpage. I have experienced persistent issues automating this scenario in both Java Bindings, and also using Protractor.

There are several discussion forums, where `dragAndDrop` issues have been discussed. One of them is [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4353), another is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607833/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor-in-angular2).

While the first one is closed and still not sure if it got solved. The latter had a luck with the code mentioned in the post, but my implementation failed to do anything. So I'm not sure if it works.

Also, you can try this [repo](https://github.com/zac11/drag_n_drop_html5), where I tried one of the solutions, using a custom JS file to achieve drag and drop in HTML5 for Angular applications.

Comment: I have tried the above answer but it does not seem to work.

Comment: what is the error that you get? And please add relevant HTML for more help.

Comment: `<tbody> <tr>  </tr> <tr> </tr> </tbody>`        The html is a web table where I need to move element in one row(<tr>) to another <tr> (row), such that it swaps the element from tr1 to tr2 and tr2 element to tr1.

Comment: It is not throwing any error and it is moving to next line of code.

Comment: Is it an angular webpage?

Comment: Yes It is a Angular webpage