# How to perform Drag and drop function in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I want to automate Drag and in my angular app.

So I tried this code like in the protractor documentation
        `browser.actions().
        dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
        perform();`

But it is not working for me.

[image: My image description here]

I need drag this **S** to the Read color area

xpath for **S** - 
    `var element1 = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-dashboard-layout/div/app-create-new-workflow/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-element-pallete/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/button'))`

xpath for Red color  - `var element2 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="form"]'))`

Can anyone help me to resolve that issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a drag and drop action in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664551/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with Mouse actions

```
await browser.actions().mouseDown(element to drag).perform();
await browser.actions().mouseMove(destination to drop).perform();
await browser.actions().mouseUp(destination to drop).perform();
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions