# drag and drop is not working in protractor typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am working on protractor typescript scripts. I am trying to automate drag and drop on a website but unable to do that.

What all I have tried:

```
let source=element(by.xpath("abc"));
let destinaton=element(by.xpath("xyz"));

1) await browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(await source.getWebElement(),await destinaton.getWebElement()).perform();
2) browser.actions().dragAndDrop(source, destinaton).perform();
3) await browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(await source.getWebElement()).
                mouseDown(await source.getWebElement()).
                mouseMove(await destinaton.getWebElement()).
                mouseUp(await destinaton.getWebElement()).
                perform();
4) await browser.driver.actions()
    .mouseMove({x: srcx, y: srcy})
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove({x: destx, y:desty})
    .mouseUp().perform();
5) var fs = require("fs");
    var dnd_js = fs.readFileSync("/abc/drag_and_drop_helper.js");
    browser.driver.executeScript(dnd_js+source+".simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: "+destination+"});")
6) var dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').code;
    browser.driver.executeScript(dragAndDrop, source, destination);
```

All the approaches mentioned above I have tried, and many more approaches but nothing is working. It is only hovering on source and destination element but dragging is not happening.

Technologies used:

Typescript : 3.0.1
protractor : 7.0.0

Please help me if there is other working work around.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52527607/9150146 I'm still using it and it's working. Please upvote if helped. If doesn't work, something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyPleshakov for your suggestion. But it is also not working.

Comment: check your locators and other areas of the code

Answer (score 1):

My problem occured when testing @angular/cdk drag and drop.

I first needed to mousemove to the drag element and instead of directly moving the element to the destination, i had to move the mouse some pixels.

```
async dragAndDrop(dragElement: WebElement, dropElement: WebElement) {
  await browser.actions().mouseMove(dragElement).perform();
  await browser.actions().mouseDown(dragElement).perform();
  await browser.actions().mouseMove({ x: 10, y: 0 }).perform();
  await browser.actions().mouseMove(dropElement).perform();
  await browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();
}
```

I combined https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/123 and https://github.com/wilgert/angular-cdk-drag-drop-protractor-issue/blob/master/e2e/src/app.po.ts#L26